# Paypal / Flash button integration as3 problems

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, paypal

I've been searching online to find ways of incorporating paypal into flash after discovering some problems which just seem bizarre and hoped others may understand why getting these to work is so painful

Dynamic text files displaying the Paypal code doesn't seem to work due to what xml validation refers to as 'bad xml structure'. Despite tidying this up and making that it fulfills both Paypal and xml's requirements, it seems that you can't get either the button to show or the xml to get beyond Error : #1085.

Trying to get Flash to addToCart or reference your cart details without going the paypal page everytime doesn't seem possible without a 3rd party cart, and trying to fuse the code from their button generator into xml arrays to achieve the same result as the buttons from your own gallery Is another issue I can't seem to get past.

I wondered if there was someway to fire ExternalInterface from flash to commit to acting on the Paypal Button code, both enabling as3 and Paypal to synchronise easily.

I've had a play with a Paypal minicart which seems a great way to bridge the two however as I can't get the Paypal button code into Flash for it to behave in the same way as their code requires.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great as I'm sure many have struggled trying to get the two to work in this way.

- (Also, considering how long Paypal and Flash have been around, it's hard to understand why their button code can't be accessed through xml!)

**Ammended examples**

If you typically try and load the code below, (as from the Paypal code generator) and include it in a standard info.xml file to use it with typical html setup, it throws up the following error code :

Error: #1085 which is a symptom of poor xml markup from what I understand as the end tag's haven't been closed, which if corrected with the following ends "/>", then fails to show on screen.

I tried correcting the tags and validating it to check for mistakes and still have the same result, and used numerous ways to import the data as html, txt, and whatnot but still no joy.

**Paypal Code**

```
<![CDATA[<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="WHATEVER YOUR BUSINESS IS">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GR">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Card - Birthday">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="BC 01-00-01">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3.25">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="23.000">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1.75">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>]]>
```

I've also tried without  tags and raw code but they all throw errors, or fail to show the data.

I have successfully managed to break down the AS3 variables for the same effect to pass to paypal on a button in an array but this results in opening a browser with every instance taking you to Paypal, where as the result needed is to continue shopping as per the button code and not end up with 10 windows adding an item everytime.

Using Paypal's Minicart allows the same result and works fine with the code above in standard html but fails in AS3 so it seems, and isn't recognised by MiniCart or similar carts either.

The option to include the button code and show either custom or Paypal buttons in xml seems simple I can't believe it's not done anywhere, and if so can't find mention or examples anywhere to reference.

My thinking was to provide if possible an ExternalInterface calling the code from an external source, Javascript or (other if possible) to access/simulate the same effect or to be able to pass the same information directly from Flash.

I know the xml is also reliant on other factors such as 'utf-8' markup and clearly strict error management in AS3 however managing to import what is in essence a simple button code seems unbelievably difficult.

Any feedback would be a blessing,

thanks,

Simon

**Amended code - Half working**

```
function onBtnClick(e:Event):void  {
//Setup the data.
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
var reqVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
reqVars.cmd = "_cart";
reqVars.business = "7BRY3X5XVSZ9Y";
reqVars.lc = "GR";
reqVars.item_name = "Card - Birthday";
reqVars.item_number = "BC 01-00-01";
reqVars.amount = "3.25";
reqVars.currency_code = "BC 01-00-01";
reqVars.button_subtype = "products";
reqVars.no_note = "0";
reqVars.cn = "Add special instructions to the seller:";
reqVars.no_shipping = "2";
reqVars.tax_rate = "23.000";
reqVars.shipping = "1.75";
reqVars.add = "1";
reqVars.bn = "PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted";

//and so on

req.data = reqVars;
sendToURL(req);
trace(reqVars);
}
```

It now registers on Paypal when I view the cart however is missed by the Paypal Minicart, so maybe it's the sending method that's in question, between the two methods is one that works, I just need to test it with other items to make sure they all register.

So close!

Comment: It will be very hard to help you when you're not providing any code.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa, just added, I needed to try and amend the markup to give it one last try before I have a breakdown over it...

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I've understood your problem correctly. And I'd say that instead of importing a lot of data just to POST some data is not really necessary. Instead I would go about something like the below. But please bear in mind that I have no experience with paypal so my solution might not be advisable.

So here's my code:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
btn = new Sprite();
btn.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
btn.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 50);
btn.graphics.endFill();
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClick);

addChild(btn);
}

private function onBtnClick(e:Event):void 
{
//Setup the data.
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.acme.com");
var reqVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
reqVars.cmd = "_cart";
reqVars.business = "WHATEVER YOUR BUSINESS IS";
reqVars.lc = "GR";
//and so on
req.data = reqVars;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(req); //Send the post data.
trace("fooo");
}
```

This code will POST a message to the relevant `url`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will try it tomorrow and get back to you first thing.

It seems plausable and similar in practice to what is going on in a standard AS3 button link with Paypal but hopefully more apt.

The issue I hope to resolve is with it being caught by the Minicart and behaving as the Paypal button code does in transit by launching the required fields without directing the user to another Paypal cart!

Either way I feel it's something that more people will benefit from as Paypal, eCommerce and AS3 is seemingly still a detached despite needing each other.

Comment: Hi @daniel, slowly getting there which is something. I tried the code and couldn't see anything happen but the trace worked, I then added all the variables as provided by the Paypal button just in case, still nothing. I then replaced the ending of the code with this as an alternative :
    [ req.data = reqVars;
    sendToURL(req);
    trace(reqVars); ]

It half works, a Temp fix for now, but on the right track. If I view the cart afterwards it now registers each press however the minicart still doesn't recognise it being fired.

Not sure why as it's technically the same as the pp button code.

Comment: Well what you should do is listen to the events fired by the URLLoader since that is the one that will get the returned information. I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you anymore since I don't have any experience with paypal and minicart.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, it did provide a half option which I can use in some areas!

Also, so many people developing sites all seem to wrestle with the two, I figure it's about time this is made easier for us as one provides the code, the other should be able to send it and make all our lives easier.

Minicart is a Javascript addon which somehow catches the Paypal coding but little info is online. For it to pick it up should be easier than this, maybe but I'll look into what you mentioned too as it's sent on a link.

Any ideas on how to get the Paypal code included in htmlText...?!

Comment: I've tried playing with the original idea you wrote, but noticed in the trace it says undefined with the following, would this be a problem, and if so what should it say?

   [ trace(loader.load(req)); ]

The reqVars is all present and correct I just thought this is maybe why it's not passing the variables to Paypal?

Comment: Additional: I've just added an event listener on the loader.load(req); to fire a trace after it was complete to see if it was happening at the same time (there-abouts) as the trace and it was, it returned data confirming that it was firing ok, just an issue somewhere to Paypal not receiving it.

I've tried various alternatives on the navigateToURL so far but not had any luck but will pursue this till I can at least get a payment to register.